# PDE solution depends continuously on $u_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, lp-spaces

I have never seen the following PDE before $b \in L^\infty([0, T] \times \mathbb{R}^d)$:
$$
\partial_t u + \mathrm{div}(bu) = \Delta u\text{ on }(0, T) \times \mathbb{R}^d, ~ u(0, x) = u_0(x)
$$
Does anyone know its name and/or has references in which case a solution (probably in $L^2([0, T]; H^1(\mathbb{R}^d))$ continuously depends on $u_0$, i.e.
$$
\lVert u(t, \cdot)\rVert_{L^2}  \leq C \lVert u_0 \rVert_{L^2}~~~?
$$

Thank you!

Comment: This is just a [convection-diffusion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation) (sometimes called advection-diffusion). I think the inequality you are after follows from energy estimates; multiply the PDE by $u$ and integrate by parts. Assuming you have some boundedness conditions at infinity, then the divergence term can be estimated relatively easily to show that the energy of the above problem is smaller than that for the usual diffusion equation $E = \int_{\Omega} u^{2}$, from which it follows that $\| u(t,\cdot) \|_{L^{2}} \le \|u_{0} \|_{L^{2}}$.

Comment: Thanky ou first of all. I managed to prove that the energy is indeed smaller. But why does then follow my estimate?

Comment: Consider the heat equation $$u_{t}=\Delta u,\quad u(\cdot,t)=u_{0}$$ Define the 'larger' energy $$E(t)=\int_{\Omega}\frac{u(\cdot,t)^{2}}{2}dx\propto\|u\|_{L^{2}}^{2}$$ Then $$E'=\int_{\Omega}uu_{t}dx=\int_{\Omega}u\Delta udx\underbrace{=}_{\text{IBP}}-\int_{\Omega}\lvert\nabla u\rvert^{2}dx\le 0$$ assuming the boundary conditions make the evaluated term vanish after IBP. $E'\le0$ implies $E$ is decreasing in time so it attains its maximum at $t=0$ and hence $$E(t)=\|u\|_{L^{2}}^{2}\le E(0)=\int_{\Omega}\frac{u(\cdot,0)^{2}}{2}dx=\int_{\Omega}\frac{u_{0}^{2}}{2}dx\propto\|u_{0}\|_{L^{2}}^{2}$$

Comment: Oh there we go, interesting. Thank you!